# Visualization of pymc priors

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc

I have using pymc successfully, I believe.  However, I would like to be able to visualize or plot a prior disctribution

```py
em0 = pymc.Normal('em0',mu=emLog, tau=1./0.3, value=emLog)
```

where `emLog` is my guess at where to find the center of the distribution

`em0` then has a number of methods but none seem to allow me to plot the distribution.

Comment: I looked a little harder at the pymc (v2?) documentation and they had the code to do just this

Comment: Is this using `pymc` or `pymc3`? I would recommend using `pymc3`, which has a function `sample_prior_predictive`. A more complete example would also be helpful -- in particular, you probably should not be using `emLog` as both the mean and the observed value of a parameter: typically there would be some unknown mean you would want to estimate _after_ observing `emLog`

Comment: More specifically:
- what statement do you use to import `pymc` above?
- is `emLog` a number, an array, or another random variable?

Comment: I am using pymc for now.  Hope to get to pymc3 when I finish this.

Comment: I just import pymc